# Regex to Extract Sass-like Key/Variable Pairs from CSS - php

Tags: php, regex, sass

how can i extract the key-value pairs with sass like variables in php?

```
$blue: #3bbfce;
$margin:16px;
```

The result should look like:

```
array('blue' => '#3bbfce', 'margin' => '16px');
```

Secondly, how can I remove (strip) all/any variable declarations made in the css stylesheet?

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$subject = '$blue: #3bbfce; \n $margin:16px;';
$pattern = '/\$(.*?):(.*?);/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
$variableArray = array_combine( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
array_map( function($val) { return ltrim($val); }, $variableArray );
print_r($variableArray);
```

This will net you the result you're looking for. To get rid of all such definitions, just use `preg_replace` over the subject with the same `$pattern`. Basically, what this regular expression says is

- Find anything starting with a $ that...

  - Is followed by an arbitrary set of characters, then a colon and another arbitrary set of characters followed by a semicolon.

You might want to refine this pattern using character classes like to so you won't match variables like `$this is not a valid variable: name`.

Comment: Thank you!!  That works brilliantly!  How can I find and replace all variables after I've built my $variableArray?

Comment: Using `preg_replace` with the same pattern (:

Comment: I guess my question is how do you modify the pattern to work with spaces before or after the colon or before the semicolon?  I'd like to ignore whitespace from the matched values.

Comment: I modified the pattern to remove trailing whitespace for the key and value but I can't figure out how to ignore preceding whitespace on the value:  $pattern = '/\$(.*?)\s*?:(.*?)\s*?;/';